# How can I regenerate the Corefile in k8s?

Tags: kubernetes, dns

My core dns corefile got corrupted somehow and now I need to regenerate it or reset it to it's default installed value. How do I do that? I've tried copying and pasting a locally-saved version of the file via `kubectl edit cm coredns -n kube-system` but I get validation errors

```
error: configmaps "coredns" is invalid                                                                                                                                                                             
A copy of your changes has been stored to "/tmp/kubectl-edit-suzaq.yaml"                                                                                                                                           
error: Edit cancelled, no valid changes were saved.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you directly edit the setting, it used to give the error.

What can you do?

> before you run anything, please take a backup:

```
kubectl -n kube-system get configmap coredns -o yaml > coredns.yaml
```

#### Ways #1, forcely apply it.

```
kubectl apply --force -f /tmp/kubectl-edit-suzaq.yaml
```

In most cases, it will apply the latest setting successfully by this way. If failed, go through the error, update the file `/tmp/kubectl-edit-suzaq.yaml` and forcely apply again.

#### Ways #2, delete and apply again.

```
kubectl -n kube-system get configmap coredns -o yaml > coredns.yaml

# do a backup, if you don't 100% sure the change will work
cp coredns.yaml coredns.yaml.orig

# update the change in coredns.yaml

# delete coredns
kubectl delete configmap coredns

# apply new change
kubectl apply -f coredns.yaml
```

Be careful, above steps will generate outage. if you work on a prod environment, you should think about to backup all kubernetes setting before doing above change.